# Can not call a helper function from another function

Tags: objective-c

I have written a helper function

```
-(NSString*) rotatePattern: (NSString*) patternToRotate
{

  int tempIndex = indexOfChar(patternToRotate,_SignatureChar);
  if(tempIndex != 0)
  {
    NSString* secondPartString = [patternToRotate substringToIndex:tempIndex-1];
    NSString* firstPartString = [patternToRotate substringFromIndex:tempIndex];
    NSMutableString *finalString;
    [finalString setString:@""];
    [finalString appendString:firstPartString];
    [finalString appendString:secondPartString];
    return finalString;
  }
 return patternToRotate;
 }
```

Now I trying to call this function from another static method using below three method it is giving me used of `undeclared identifier rotatePattern` or `use of undeclared identifier self`

```
_finalPattern = [rotatePattern: @"hello"];
```

OR

```
_finalPattern = [self rotatePattern: @"hello"];
```

OR

```
_finalPattern = [self.rotatePattern: @"hello"];
```

Comment: is the function `rotatePattern` being used in static method? (aka has a + in front of the method)

Comment: It is called in a static method. Has the keyword static infront of it.

Comment: "use of undeclared identifier self" sounds like you're trying to call the method from a _function_ (as in: `void foo() { ... }`) as opposed to a _method_.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, make `rotatePattern` a static method, then you can use it like

`[self rotatePattern: @"hello"];` if its within the same class

or `[ThatClassName rotatePattern: @"hello"];` if its called from another class (or this class, this is the more politically correct way to do it)

otherwise if you cant make this method static, you can try make the other one non-static.

if both of those are an issue, what you are trying to do is not possible, since calling an instance method without an instance of the class doesnt make sense.

Comment: How can I make the rotatePAttern a static method? Can you provide me the syntax of how declaring it as static?

Comment: I have added a + instead of - to make it a class method still self is not detecting it.

Comment: did you change it in the header as well?

Comment: check if you changed it in the header. also make sure that no instance variables/methods are called from inside a static method.